# Bad Javascript Coding and Drop Down Boxes

Tags: javascript, html

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBuys1290/ksuh95w2/32/) is a jsfiddle I made to show you what I'd like help with.

Need help with updating select box values

I've tried using 3 for loop constructs to update my drop down box, but my bad Javascript skills don't let me achieve this.

```js
var units = [
  ['Volts', 1],
  ['Millivolts', .001],
  ['Microvolts', 0.000001]
];
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.Voltage');

for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < selectors.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = units[i][1];
    option.textContent = units[i][0];
    selectors[j].add(option);
  }
}

var units = [
  ['Amps', 1],
  ['Milliamperes', .001],
  ['Microamperes', 0.000001]
];
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.Current');

for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < selectors.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = units[i][1];
    option.textContent = units[i][0];
    selectors[j].add(option);
  }
}

var units = [
  ['Ohms', 1],
  ['Milliohms', .001],
  ['Microohms', 0.000001]
];
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.Resistance');

for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < selectors.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = units[i][1];
    option.textContent = units[i][0];
    selectors[j].add(option);
  }
}


function EqualsVoltage() {

  var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
  var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
  var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;
  if (Resistance != "0" && Current != "0") {
    document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value = parseFloat(Current * Resistance).toExponential();
  }


}

function EqualsCurrent() {

  var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
  var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
  var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;
  if (Voltage != "0" && Resistance != "0") {
    document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value = parseFloat(Voltage / Resistance).toExponential();
  }
}

function EqualsResistance() {

  var Voltage = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
  var Current = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
  var Resistance = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;

  if (Voltage != "0" && Current != "0") {
    document.getElementById("inputResistance").value = parseFloat(Voltage / Current).toExponential();
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <br>

  <select style="float:left" id="EANDM1" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container Voltage" oninput="EqualsResistance(); EqualsCurrent()" onchange="EqualsResistance(); EqualsCurrent()">
  </select>

  <label>Voltage:</label>
  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="inputVoltage" type="number" oninput="EqualsResistance(); EqualsCurrent()" value="0"> </p>

  <select style="float:left" id="EANDM2" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container Current" oninput="EqualsVoltage(); EqualsResistance()" onchange="EqualsVoltage(); EqualsResistance()">
  </select>

  <p>
    <label>Current:</label>
    <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="inputCurrent" type="number" oninput="EqualsVoltage(); EqualsResistance()" value="0"> </p>

  <select style="float:left" id="EANDM3" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container Resistance" oninput="EqualsCurrent();EqualsVoltage()" onchange="EqualsCurrent();EqualsVoltage()">
  </select>

  <p>
    <label>Resistance:</label>
    <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="inputResistance" type="number" oninput="EqualsCurrent();EqualsVoltage()" value="0"> </p>

</body>

</html>
```

When I switch to millivolts in the drop down box, the values for Current and Resistance should change after I've filled in 2 values in their respective drop down boxes. Please help me get the drop down box to change the values for the input fields. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple problems.

```
parseFloat(Current * Resistance)
```

This doesn't work because `Current` and `Resistance` are strings, but you're multiplying them *before* you parse them. Instead, parse them before you multiply them:

```
parseFloat(Current) * parseFloat(Resistance)
```

Another problem, related to the recalculation when selecting something from one of the drop-down boxes, is that you aren't pulling out or using the factors. So the units never change.

Here is a quick tidying up I did of the calculation code that takes into account the selected units and converts values before doing the calculation. (I also removed the `toExponential` calls to see what was happening a bit more easily.)

Extracted the code that gets the values from the controls to its own function. This could still be improved further.

```
function GetValues() {
  const voltageText = document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value;
  const currentText = document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value;
  const resistanceText = document.getElementById("inputResistance").value;

  const voltageFactorText = document.getElementById("EANDM1").value;
  const currentFactorText = document.getElementById("EANDM2").value;
  const resistanceFactorText = document.getElementById("EANDM3").value;

  const voltageValue = parseFloat(voltageText);
  const currentValue = parseFloat(currentText);
  const resistanceValue = parseFloat(resistanceText);

  const voltageFactor = parseFloat(voltageFactorText);      
  const currentFactor = parseFloat(currentFactorText);
  const resistanceFactor = parseFloat(resistanceFactorText);

  const voltage = voltageValue / voltageFactor;
  const current = currentValue / currentFactor;
  const resistance = resistanceValue / resistanceFactor;

  return [voltage, current, resistance];
}
```

And then the three recalculation functions:

```
function EqualsVoltage() {
  const [voltage, current, resistance] = GetValues();      
  if (!resistance || !current)
    return;

  document.getElementById("inputVoltage").value = current * resistance;
}

function EqualsCurrent() {
  const [voltage, current, resistance] = GetValues();
  if (!voltage || !resistance)
    return;

  document.getElementById("inputCurrent").value = voltage / resistance;
}

function EqualsResistance() {
  const [voltage, current, resistance] = GetValues();      
  if (!voltage || !current)
    return;

  document.getElementById("inputResistance").value = voltage / current;
}
```